# (Entity Framework) context.Database.SqlQuery return invalid object name for table but LINQ query works

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm working on an MVC web app using Entity Framework 6. I can't figure out why I can query with LINQ but context.Database.SqlQuery() doesn't work and always returns an invalid object name error for the table.

This works:

```
db.MatchHistory.Where(u => u.id == sumID).ToList().Count()
```

This doesn't. I also tried tblMatchHistory and dbo.tblMatchHistory.

```
db.MatchHistory.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tblMatchHistory] WHERE id = '" + sumID + "'").ToList().Count()
```

What am I missing? Or should I just not be using SqlQuery()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use count() in SQL like

```
int nCount= db.MatchHistory.SqlQuery("SELECT COUNT(id) as id FROM [dbo].[tblMatchHistory] WHERE id = '" + sumID + "'");
```

Comment: That's true, I should have, but I have another SqlQuery() line without a count and it has the same problem.